# iPhone: Adding Info button as right bar button item in navigation bar in code

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

Has anyone had any success creating an info button (italic 'i' in a circle) in code (read: without Interface Builder), and then assigning it as the right bar button item of a navigation bar?

I've looked everywhere, and I can't even find how to create an info button in code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Reena. I've marked it as the accepted answer, but if you'd be so kind as to forgive my cheekiness, may I ask how one might bring the info button to left by five pixels or so? Adding it as the right bar button item means it gets quite crushed up against the right side of the screen.

Comment: using 'leftBarButtonItem' property you can set at left
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

Comment: Sorry Reena. I do want it as the right bar button item, I just want to add a little bit of space on the right (thereby bringing the right button 5px to the left). Is that possible?

Comment: you can do this by using 'titleview' property of 'navigationItem'.
Take one uiview and add all controls you want to show on navigationbar including title and set frame of controls as you want and set this view as titleview of navigationItem.

Comment: Also, how do I add a target and action to this info button? Sorry I keep asking so many questions! :P

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: `[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Just thought I'd add to this, I just discovered an easier way to add padding with the info button if you edit the frame and make the width larger, it will look like it's further across (at least from the left).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a pretty good looking solution that I think covers all the points people brought up in the comments above. Similar to the accepted answer, but this approach includes extra spacing (via modifying the frame) so that the button isn't smashed up against the right edge.

```
// Create the info button
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

// Adjust the frame by adding an addition 10 points to its width so the button is padded nicely
infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(infoButton.frame.origin.x, infoButton.frame.origin.y, infoButton.frame.size.width + 10.0, infoButton.frame.size.height);

// Hook the button up to an action
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfoScreen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add the button to the nav bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];

// Also make sure to add a showInfoScreen method to your class!
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift:

```
func addRightNavigationBarInfoButton() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .infoDark)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showInfoScreen), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}

@objc func showInfoScreen() {
    // info bar button pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be more complete response and it should help in any situation:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    //Set Navigation Bar
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

    //Set title if needed
    UINavigationItem * navTitle = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    navTitle.title = @"Title";

    //Here you create info button and customize it
    UIButton * tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

    //Add selector to info button
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem * infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempButton];

    //In this case your button will be on the right side
    navTitle.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton;

    //Add NavigationBar on main view
    navBar.items = @[navTitle];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

}
```