# create info button in navigation bar without using a navigation controller

Tags: ios

I'm trying to customize my navigation bar by changing the right bar button item to the classic info light.
As I dont want to use a navigation controller the code proposed in the linked question does not work.

[iPhone: Adding Info button as right bar button item in navigation bar in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492226/iphone-adding-info-button-as-right-bar-button-item-in-navigation-bar-in-code)

Has anybody an idea how I could change the appearance of a barButtonItem without implementing a navigation controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
UIBarButtonItem  *barButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
UIView *barButtonView = [barButton valueForKey:@"view"];
barButtonView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-barButtonView.frame.size.width,
                                 0,
                                 barButtonView.frame.size.width,
                                 barButtonView.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:barButtonView];
```

Comment: Very creative solution. Thank you. The only problem with that solution is that I can't connect an action to the button as it is possible with the class methods like e.g.[ initWithTitle: style: target: action:]  Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: Found a solution: by adding a gestureRecognizer and assign it to the barButtonView. UITapGestureRecognizer *taprecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)];
    [barButtonView addGestureRecognizer:taprecognizer];

Answer (score 1):

On your UIViewController you can add UINavigationBar and simply add bar button item on it. It will give you feel like controller is UINavigationController but it is simply UIViewController having bar button on it.
Now to change bar button appearance you can use following code 
UIBarButtonItem  *barButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:@"info.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onBarButtonDidTap:);

Comment: That solution works as well. Do you know if there is a standard info.png image within the framework? Because if I add an own image that looks just similar to the original, apple might not let the app pass the review for the appstore...

Comment: No framework is not provided any such image. Either you can use your own or you can use the solution given by Jamil. AndIn Jamil's solution you can use "setTarget" ans "setAction" method to set all required properties.